# Customizing Symfony/Twig form theme, how to detect "global" errors?

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to customize errors rendering in Twig. My theme extends `form_div_layout.html.twig`, and the block controlling errors rendering is:

```
{% block form_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

How can I distinguish between field errors from "global" form errors? I mean distinguish between an error in the `name` field and the `token` CSFR error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can use errors variable in your row or type block twig.

(example from my own code)

```
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="control-group {% if errors %}alert alert-danger{% endif %}">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_label(form, label, { 'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'} }) }}
        <div class="controls">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}
```